# Trying to Create a Loop That will Start and End on Specific Sheets

Tags: loops, excel, excel-2007, vba

I am new to VBA. I am trying to create a set of code that will allow me to start and stop a loop in between a set of worksheets.

Background: I have a file that I use to update several important factors for financial analysis and certain tabs are grouped together. Since this file is always adding and subtracting tabs, I cant set a loop for a set number of worksheets. I do have a set of tabs that are never moved in between each grouping.

So I would like to create a loop that will start at tab "X+1" and loop until it reaches tab "Y-1", as I dont want the loop to ac. The code inbetween I already have written and worked out, but I'm not very good at looping yet.

Comment: Please consider adding more, relevant tags to your question. It'll improve the chances that it will be seen by people who are able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i as integer
For i = X+1 to Y-1
   Sheets(i).Select
    .... your code
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks John. I was thinking something similar but am running into a bit of a snag.

Comment: For some reason, it keeps telling me that the object isnt supporting the property. I am trying to set X and Y = to the sheet names but maybe I am wrong. Can I not set X = Sheets("Sheet1") or is there suppose to be a .Index or something on the end?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to loop over several worksheets in the current workbook is:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim wrksheet As Worksheet

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Set wkrsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    'Do work on wrksheet object
Next i
```

You can loop on any subset of the Sheets collection by starting on a number greater than 1 or ending on a number less than Sheets.Count, but make sure you don't exceed those bounds.

If you wish to filter out certain sheets, you can skip logic based on sheet names, by checking `wrksheet.Name`.

Make sure you aren't using logic that involves `Sheet.Select` or `.Activate`, this will only lead to trouble down the road. Your code should always operate on Worksheet objects by direct reference rather than relying on state dependent variables like `ActiveSheet`.